# Reducing Sample Size from Data Set

Tags: sampling, down-sample

I have a large data set where the number of unit is around 300,000 (given that the original data is in a panel setting, the number of observations is larger than 300,000). For the efficiency of running analysis (e.g. regressions), I want to reduce the sample size and play around with the sampled data set.

While a random sampling approach seems to be fine, but I also want to draw out the samples which can represent the original samples. One approach I can think of is to use a set of characteristics variables and store the units among a set of units which have same/similar characteristics.

This may sounds like implementing matching algorithms (e.g. propensity score matching) between treatment and control groups, but in this setting, I want to sample out from the original data set which is regardless of treatment and control groups.

Is there a clever way for this process?

Comment: It sounds like a stratified sample based on a few important characteristics of the units and treatment/control condition could be reasonable?

Comment: The best way to "draw out the samples which can represent the original" data is simple random sampling.